# Why I cannot refer to the images array?

Tags: javascript, html

i try to swap the images continuously from the array, but the code does not get the image source, why this happened?

```
function nextPic(){
    var picCollection =["pic_bulbon.gif","pic_bulboff.gif"];
    for(i=0; i<picCollection.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("myImage").src = picCollection[i].src;
    }
}

function triggers(){
    setInterval(nextPic,500);
}
```

Comment: maybe it doesn't know the location of the image files. you can try with stock images from online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be Your code should be

```
var picCollection =["pic_bulbon.gif","pic_bulboff.gif"];
var i=0;
var interval;
function nextPic(){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = picCollection[i];
    // if you want to repeat for show image again and again tehn use below line
    i= (i+1) % picCollection.length;

    // if you want not to repeat again then use below line
    // if(i+1>=picCollection.length) clearInterval(interval);
   
}

function triggers(){
    interval=setInterval(nextPic,500);
}
```

Here you have to define the image name array in global which should be accessible in all desire functions. It is good if you store setInterval reference in variable and clear it by clearInterval.

Answer (score 2):

You need create a global variable for picture number. Then use that inside callback passed to `setInterval`. The above code will only show the last image of array.

```js
let pic = 0;
const picCollection =["pic_bulbon.gif","pic_bulboff.gif"];

function nextPic(){
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = picCollection[pic];
  console.log("The pic shown is ", picCollection[pic])
  pic++;
  if(pic === picCollection.length){
    pic = 0;
  }
}

function triggers(){
    setInterval(nextPic,500);
}

triggers()
```

```html
<img id="myImage"/>
```

Comment: can I know why I need to set it to a global variable? Why use for loop does not work?

Comment: @user14811578 loops are synchronous(Meaning that one block will immediately run after another). But in your case you want a delay of `500ms`. You need to set `pic` as global variable because if you set it inside the function you will lose the track of currect image. And you should declare `picCollection` as global variable to prevent declaration of same variable again and again.

Comment: @user14811578 If you don't understand you can ask.

Comment: ok. Understand now. very appreciate for the help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `src` key in your arrat. You can just use

`document.getElementById("myImage").src = picCollection[i];`

Comment: There are other problems as well I guess

Comment: You are correct but the code will still not work. The code will always show the last image and with `i` without `let` will show no image. Test the code again and try to resolve all the issues

Answer (score -1):

Your code should look something similar to below

```
function nextPic(){
  var picCollection = ["./pic_bulbon.gif","./pic_bulboff.gif"];

  for(i = 0; i < picCollection.length; i++){
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = picCollection[i];
  }
}
```

`"./pic_bulbon.gif"` may need to change based off of your file structure and where you are storing the gif you are trying to access.

If you could supply a screenshot of your file structure I could tell you exactly what you need

The other issue you are having is your trying to access  `picCollection[i].src`

but `picCollection[i]` is only an array of string not objects.

Comment: This will always show the last image because look will always go to end. Please check my answer. Also you shouldn't use `i` without let in loop. Otherwise it will become global variable

Comment: I put it in the same folder with the js files, i guess location is not the main problem